# How to ignore MultiMap class member to write in document DB azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, multimap

I have already tried this :

```
@JsonIgnore
```

Removed Lombok and manually written @JsonIgnore on getter and setter of property

My property looks like this :

```
public Multimap<String, String> getmultiMapField() {
return multiMapField;
```

}
I have both no argument and parameterised constructors.

But every time this field is getting saved in db with no value.

How to remove this field before saving in db

Comment: Can someone look into this issue?